# Recursive md5 hashing benchmark function returns highly varying latencies

Tags: javascript, node.js

### Consider the following NodeJS program.

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var overall = new Date().getMilliseconds();

var hashme = function myself(times){
    times--;
    if(times > 0){
        var name = new Buffer(100000).toString('utf8') + times;
        var hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(name).digest("hex");
        console.log(hash);
        myself(times)
    }
    else{
        return console.log('Finished in ' + (new Date().getMilliseconds() - overall) + 'ms.')
    }
}

hashme(400)
```

It creates a new string buffer of 10000 bytes, salts it with the iterated value, then calculates the md5 sum of the buffer and logs the elapsed time when finished.

When I run the program, I get wildly different results between 200ms and 600ms each time it is run.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a Buffer and calling `toString()` is going to be a part of that latency. So you're timing more than just hashing there. Take the Buffer creation and `toString()` out of the equation and you'll get a much more accurate and precise reading.